# Azure DevOps - require PR re-approval if PR is updated after initial approval

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps, consider the following sequence of events

1. PR is created by developer, not marked as auto-complete
2. PR is reviewed and approved by the reviewer (requrired policy is atleast 1 reviewer)
3. Additional changes are made by the developer, PR gets updated automatically
4. PR is completed and includes the changes made in (3) above, which are not reviewed by anyone

How do we ensure that any additional changes done to an already approved PR needs to be re-approved?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an option on the Pull Request policy that supports this.  Check the [documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#require-a-minimum-number-of-reviewers)

[image]

> - If Requestors can approve their own changes isn't selected, the creator of the pull request can still vote Approve on their pull
>   request, but their vote won't count toward the Minimum number of
>   reviewers.
> - If any reviewer rejects the changes, the pull request can't finish unless you select Allow completion even if some reviewers vote to wait
>   or reject.
> - **You can reset code reviewer votes when new changes are pushed to the source branch. Select Reset code reviewer votes when there are new**
>   **changes**.

Answer (score 4):

You need to mark this checkbox:

[image]